Opencv android using using CAP_MJPEG nor CAP_GSTREAMER unable to get frames from ESP32 camera stream
I am trying to capture frames from an esp32-cam set up to my android phone, hoping to be able to do object detection from that esp32-cam's stream. I know my esp32 is also oputting a MJPEG stream, and that Gstreamer may be necessary to interface the video stream to opencv. However, using CAP_MJPEG nor CAP_GSTREAMER  does not work.

Trying to use the MJPEG stream directly

code if i were to use purely the url with ip address i.e.  http://192.168.0.100 (ip addresses 100 to 105 are all valid, i can see the camera webserver if i open the URL in a web browser)
var urlWithIpAddress = getUrlWithIpAddressFromGStreamerCommand(streamAddress)
var fullGStreamerCommand = "gst-launch-1.0 " + streamAddress // gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc etc etc....
//actual code meant for reading from the gstreamer lib
lifecycleScope.launch {
    var videoCapturing = VideoCapture(urlWithIpAddress, CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG)
    videoCapturing.open(urlWithIpAddress, CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG)

Logcat output
app_function Creating pipeline in CustomData at 0xb40000709a195810
app_function custom pipeline string: souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.0.100 ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
urlWithIpAddress is http://192.168.0.100
[ WARN:0@26.437] global cap.cpp:206 open VIDEOIO(CV_MJPEG): backend is generally available but can't be used to capture by name
[ WARN:0@26.438] global cap.cpp:206 open VIDEOIO(CV_MJPEG): backend is generally available but can't be used to capture by name


Trying to use with GStreamer

i read somewhere that opencv may be unable to get frames directly unless paired with gstreamer or ffmpeg (though the post is from 2018)
when trying to get frames from my esp32 camera using the following Gstreamer pipeline commmand
souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.0.102 ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink 

i encounter the problems failures as noted by my logging statements. Also, it seems like adding the "gst-launch-1.0" to the front of the statement, and specifying CAP_GSTREAMER did not help.
var urlWithIpAddress = getUrlWithIpAddressFromGStreamerCommand(streamAddress)
var fullGStreamerCommand = "gst-launch-1.0 " + streamAddress // gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc etc etc....
//actual code meant for reading from the gstreamer lib
lifecycleScope.launch {
    var videoCapturing = VideoCapture(fullGStreamerCommand, CAP_GSTREAMER)
    videoCapturing.open(fullGStreamerCommand, CAP_CAP_GSTREAMER)

here is what my log shows (i have also added other logging statements to see what i pass into the videocapture variable as well as to check if isOpened returns true or false.)
urlWithIpAddress is http://192.168.0.100
videoCapturing opening:  gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.0.100 ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink 
videoCapturing isOpened:  false 
videoCapturing isOpened():  false 
Video capture failed, no frames obtained. videoCapturing.isOpened returned false. 
video capture releasing!  

Edit:
i found a new error in my logs. It doesnt always appear
OpenCV(4.8.0) Error: Requested object was not found (could not open directory: /data/app/~~h0G0FSTdUBM1n2pgU7YM8g==/com.pkgname.streamplayer-fI_rhcyXiIM5ZinT8OdKFg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64) in glob_rec, file /home/ci/opencv/modules/core/src/glob.cpp, line 279

I have consulted these links but unable to solve my problem

Getting camera frames from openCV output not the original frames of the cam  -- suggests to use opencv with gstreamer which is what I have tried.

Read frames from a HTTP webcam using opencv videocapture in Kotlin -- no responses on this thread

https://forum.opencv.org/t/possibility-to-get-ip-camera-stream-from-url-and-get-frame-in-android-mobile-app/1518 -- no responses on this thread

https://answers.opencv.org/question/226976/opencv-with-gstreamer-in-android-studio/ -- no responses on this thread

https://answers.opencv.org/question/170387/android-opencv/ -- no responses on this thread

Grabbing consecutive frames in android using opencv and read successive frames OpenCV using cvQueryframe -- i am unable to find the functions used in the marked answer. Since the post is 13 years ago, i assume these functions don't exist anymore.

How to get MJPG stream video from android IPWebcam using opencv -- i added the dummy variables to the url in the pipeline, it didnt work either.

GStreamer API in OpenCV: autovideosink vs appsink -- adding appsink didnt help.


Could anyone weigh in on what I could perhaps try to do?
Or are there other options other than using opencv + gstreamer?
Thank you :)

CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG is for local files in AVI containers, not for network streams.

@ChristophRackwitz ahh icic. Alright that leaves the CAP_GSTREAMER as my only hope. Thanks!

depends. if native android APIs support your network stream, you can either use those directly, or check whether OpenCV can use them (backend choice). or you find a library that does, and use that.
